# Pandas: create columns with deviation from mean in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider the following `DataFrame` in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0]*3+[1]*3,'y':np.random.randn(6),'x':np.random.randn(6)})
```

which gives

```
   id         y         x
0   0  0.721757  1.595646
1   0  0.359601  1.128473
2   0  1.134922  2.317929
3   1  0.290152 -1.901336
4   1  0.128742  0.982683
5   1  0.556914  0.745208
```

Note that `y` and `x` are grouped according to `id`. I want to creat the following `DataFrame`

```
   id         y         x      y_md      x_md
0   0  0.721757  1.595646 -0.017003 -0.085037
1   0  0.359601  1.128473 -0.379159 -0.552209
2   0  1.134922  2.317929  0.396162  0.637246
3   1  0.290152 -1.901336 -0.035117 -1.843521
4   1  0.128742  0.982683 -0.196527  1.040498
5   1  0.556914  0.745208  0.231644  0.803023
```

where

- `y_md` contains the value of deviation from its group mean (`id`=`0` & `1`)
- `x_md` contains the value of deviation from its group mean (`id`=`0` & `1`)

What I came up with is

```
df_g = df.groupby('id')
yy = pd.Series( df['y'].values - df_g['y'].mean().repeat(3).values )
xx = pd.Series( df['x'].values - df_g['x'].mean().repeat(3).values )
pd.concat([df,yy.rename('y_md'), xx.rename('x_md')],axis=1)
```

but it does not look good to me. I wonder if there is an elegant one liner or similar for the same result? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for processing multiple columns, subtract by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
c = ['x','y']
df = df.join(df[c].sub(df.groupby('id')[c].transform('mean')).add_suffix('_md'))
print (df)
   id         y         x      x_md      y_md
0   0  0.721757  1.595646 -0.085037 -0.017003
1   0  0.359601  1.128473 -0.552210 -0.379159
2   0  1.134922  2.317929  0.637246  0.396162
3   1  0.290152 -1.901336 -1.843521 -0.035117
4   1  0.128742  0.982683  1.040498 -0.196527
5   1  0.556914  0.745208  0.803023  0.231645
```

Or is possible assign new columns names:

```
df[['x_md','y_md']] = df[['x','y']].sub(df.groupby('id')[['x','y']].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: `GroupBy.transform` is the one I was looking for. Excellent! But it is unfortunate that the link you gave (the official site) does not give any clue about what it does.

Comment: is there any reason to use `.join` over `concat`, usually i use contact as `pd.concat([df, df[c].sub(df.groupby("id")[c].transform("mean")).add_suffix("_md")],axis="columns",)`, but I'm wondering if there's an argument (other than being cleaner, which is enough) for join over concat in something like the above example

Comment: @baxx - I only used `join` because shortier code ;) Sure, also `pd.concat` is possible used here.

Answer (score 1):

Set `id` as index, groupby the index and subtract the mean of the grouping from df :

```
df = df.set_index("id")

df[['y_md','x_md']] = df.sub(df.groupby("id").agg("mean"))

df

       y           x            y_md      x_md
id              
0   0.721757    1.595646    -0.017003   -0.085037
0   0.359601    1.128473    -0.379159   -0.552210
0   1.134922    2.317929    0.396162    0.637246
1   0.290152    -1.901336   -0.035117   -1.843521
1   0.128742    0.982683    -0.196527   1.040498
1   0.556914    0.745208    0.231645    0.803023
```